# sql order and order_items tables but show shipping charge only once

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have two tables orders and order_items

**orders table**

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id | total_shipping_charge |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | 60                    |
|  2 | 60                    |
|  3 | 60                    |
|  4 | 60                    |
|  5 | 60                    |
|  6 | 0                     |
|  7 | 60                    |
|  8 | 0                     |
|  9 | 60                    |
| 10 | 60                    |
+----+-----------------------+
```

**order_items table**

```
+----+--------------------------+-----+-------+-
| id | order_id | p_name        | qty | price |
+----+----------+---------------+-----+-------+---------------------------------
|  1 |        1 | Product 1     |  1  | 699   |
|  2 |        2 | Product 2     |  1  | 349   |
|  3 |        3 | Product 3     |  1  | 199   |
|  4 |        4 | Product x     |  2  | 299   |
|  5 |        4 | Product y     |  2  | 299   |
|  6 |        4 | Product z     |  2  | 299   |
|  7 |        5 | Product 7     |  2  | 299   |
|  8 |        6 | Product 8     |  1  | 1299  |
|  9 |        7 | Product 9     |  1  | 199   |
| 10 |        8 | Product 10    |  6  | 349   |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now order_id 4 has multiple products in a single order and when I join two tables I get duplicate shipping cost. I want shipping cost on first raw only.

I ran this query

```
SELECT
    o1.id,
    o1.total_shipping_charge,
    o2.order_id,
    o2.p_name
FROM
    orders o1
INNER JOIN order_items o2 ON o1.id = o2.order_id
```

but it shows duplicate row for shipping cost, it should show for first row only.

```
| id | total_shipping_charge | order_id | p_name
+----+-----------------------+----------+---------+
|  1 | 60                    |        1 | Product 1  
|  2 | 60                    |        2 | Product 2
|  3 | 60                    |        3 | Product 3
|  4 | 60                    |        4 | Product x
|  5 | 60                    |        4 | Product y
|  6 | 60                    |        4 | Product z 
|  7 | 0                     |        6 | Product 7
|  8 | 60                    |        7 | Product 8
|  9 | 0                     |        8 | Product 9
```

Answer (score 1):

From Sql Server perspective, what you are asking for is not possible. You are asking from a report point of view which is something different. You can pull this data and on the report show it the way you want but you can't pull the data this way.

Not sure how MySql behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT o1.id,o1.total_shipping_charge, distinct o2.order_id,o2.p_name FROM orders o1 INNER JOIN order_items o2 ON o1.id=o2.order_id
```

Comment: Hi OscarAkaElvism I also had tried DISTINCT but it shows error with this. 9 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "distinct" at position 39)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "distinct" at position 39)
Unexpected token. (near "o2" at position 48)
Unexpected token. (near "." at position 50)
Unexpected token. (near "order_id" at position 51)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 59)
Unexpected token. (near "o2" at position 60)
Unexpected token. (near "." at position 62)
Unexpected token. (near "p_name" at position 63)